# How to map an NHibernate entity property using both a formula and a column specification

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm trying to map an entity property in such way that it writes its value to a database column but retrieves its value using a formula.

To focus on the actual issue, I have simplified the example. In reality the formula is a bit more complex and is using an NHibernate filter.

```
<many-to-one cascade="all" class="Thing" lazy="false" name="MyThing"
    formula="(SELECT Things.Value FROM Things WHERE Things.Id = MyThingId)">
    <column name="MyThingId" />
</many-to-one>
```

The formula is ignored however, unless I remove the `<column name="MyThingId" />` line.

How would I fix this mapping in order to have NHibernate use the formula?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do exactly what you are trying.

Why not split the property in two? One readonly for the formula and the other read/write with a direct column mapping...

If you still want a single access point, you can map a third ignored propery that implements it's `get` and `set` accessors with the two first properties.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using a two properties instead of one, one to provide persistence and another to facilitate retrieval using the formula.